# Unknown URL content://media/external/images/media at android.content.ContentResolver.insert

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL
> content://media/external/images/media
> at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1837)

with some device.where the faulty device is Redmi 9A

```
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, fileName);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, getMimeType(context, Uri.parse(pathFile)));
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER);
        // add datetime
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED, now);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED, now);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_TAKEN, now);
        //Media image.
        Uri uriTarget = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
```

Comment: Does Android version of device differ?

Comment: Android device 10.

Comment: `Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER` What would that be?

Comment: this is number 1

Comment: Even if it does it is unreadable code.

Comment: Have the same bug report, from the same device (Redmi 9A). Did you figure it out by chance?

Comment: Hi Dimezis, no ;((

Comment: Have the same bug report, from the same device Redmi Note 7S. Anyone is figured out? @Dimezis

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi @AnkitBatra no:(((

Comment: We see it as well for the same `Redmi 9A`

Comment: Does any solution find?

Comment: no :(. i not find solution on device.